# References without parenthesis

Tags: postgresql

I do not understand the difference between:

```
CREATE TABLE country(
   name VARCHAR,
   capital VARCHAR
);
CREATE TABLE people(
   name VARCHAR,
   grade INTEGER ,
   country VARCHAR,
   PRIMARY KEY (name, country),
   FOREIGN KEY country REFERENCES country(name)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE country(
   name VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
   capital VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE people(
   name VARCHAR,
   grade INTEGER ,
   country VARCHAR,
   PRIMARY KEY (name, country),
   FOREIGN KEY country REFERENCES country
);
```

In particular, I'm unsure how the second one is interpreted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omitting the column name(s) from the foreign key constraint means that the constraint will refer to the primary key of the targeted table. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

> You can also shorten the above command to:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders (
>     order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
>     product_no integer REFERENCES products,
>     quantity integer
> );
> ```
>
> because in absence of a column list the primary key of the referenced
> table is used as the referenced column(s).

and in the [`CREATE TABLE` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtable.html):

> ```
> REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ] [ MATCH matchtype ] [ ON DELETE referential_action ] [ ON UPDATE referential_action ] (column constraint)
> FOREIGN KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn [, ... ] ) ] [ MATCH matchtype ] [ ON DELETE referential_action ] [ ON UPDATE referential_action ] (table constraint)
> ```
>
> These clauses specify a foreign key constraint, which requires that a
> group of one or more columns of the new table must only contain values
> that match values in the referenced column(s) of some row of the
> referenced table. If the refcolumn list is omitted, the primary key of
> the reftable is used. The referenced columns must be the columns of a
> non-deferrable unique or primary key constraint in the referenced
> table.

Comment: And what's going on, if the primary is key is a set of attributes?

Comment: @Ievgeni Then it would reference all of them. Which causes a column number mismatch when you declare only `product_no` to be the referencing column.

Answer (score 1):

In postgres for create foreign keys you should like `FOREIGN KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn [, ... ] ) ]` format

For see more about create table read document: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createtable.html

Sample 1:

```sql
CREATE TABLE country
(
    name    VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    capital VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE people
(
    name    VARCHAR,
    grade   INTEGER,
    country VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, country),
    FOREIGN KEY (country) REFERENCES country (name)
);
```

Sample 2:

```sql
CREATE TABLE country
(
    name    VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    capital VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE people
(
    name    VARCHAR,
    grade   INTEGER,
    country VARCHAR REFERENCES country (name),
    PRIMARY KEY (name, country)
);
```

Comment: But, what does the second implementation (in my post)?